# Exceptions not shown in console (spring mvc/security)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, roo

I'm having a spring-mvc project set up with spring-roo, that runs on tomcat. 
After setting up spring-security, I can not see exceptions/stacktrace in the console anymore...

I just go to the login page and try to login. In my UserService (that is called during the login process) I throw a NullPointerException to "test" this.
The Exception is not shown in the console. The only thing I can see, is the message of the exception on the login page (/login?login_error=t) like "Your login attempt was not successful, try again. Reason: blablabla".

That is not good, because I want to be able to see (in console) what is going on an where the problem is.

I commented out the filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' that was added when setting up spring-security.
When I throw an exception within a controller, the exception is shown in console as expected. So my guess is, that something handles the exception during the Filter chain and does not print it to the console. I wasn't able to find out, how to avoid this...

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, `spring-security` is taking care of the authentication part, so all you need is set the log level of `spring-security` to **DEBUG**

```
org.springframework.security.level=DEBUG
```

This should print all the exceptions which are occurring while authenticating.

Comment: I changed the log level, but that doesn't do it. I can see the following line in the log now: "DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: blablabla". The stacktrace of the original exception is still missing. And: it is not nice to see the full debug messages of spring security. If something is wrong I just would like to see the exception...